# Hosts declared in ssh configuration on Windows are not visible

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am using Git on Windows with Git Bash.

In `C:\Users\myuser\.ssh` I created a `config` file, where I declared a host
 `Host my-host` along with some configuration.

The config file has the following content:

```
Host my-host
        User my-username
        Hostname my-repo.com
        Port 7999
        IdentityFile id_rsa
```

In theory, I should be able to connect to this host from the command line:

`ssh my-host`.

However, that doesn't happen, if try to run this command from Git Bash, I get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname my-host: Name or service not known
```

So how can I make this host visible in Git Bash or in Windows Command Line?

Comment: Please, show config file content

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

- Check port number, 7999 is not usual for ssh
- set full path for id_rsa, like ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- maybe you should use alias name without "-"
- check connection with your parameters without alias, like "ssh -i~/.ssh/id_rsa -p7999 user@host"
- check you id_rsa, is it private key?
- check rights on folder and file: ~/.ssh - 700, ~/.ssh/config - 600